# Rate limited computed firing twice

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a simple `isDirty` style Knockout binding. I've seen examples using the `toJS` conversion but it gets a little complicated using this approach for multiple firing of the observable. As I know the observable I want to subscribe to up-front I thought I'd just do that instead. Here's the code I've currently got:

```
var isDirty = false;
this.types = ko.observableArray([]);
this.instances = ko.observableArray([]);
this.selection = ko.observable();
this.filters = ko.observableArray([]);

// Some Logging to try and figure out what's going on
this.types.subscribe(function() { console.log("types changed " + new Date().getTime()) });
this.instances.subscribe(function() { console.log("instances changed " + new Date().getTime()) });
this.selection.subscribe(function() { console.log("selection changed " + new Date().getTime()) });
this.filters.subscribe(function() { console.log("filters changed " + new Date().getTime()) });

   // Flag to use to determine if the context property has changed
this.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
    console.log("isDirty changed " + new Date().getTime());
    let types = self.types();
    let instances = self.instances();
    let selection = self.selection();
    let filters = self.filters();
    return isDirty = !isDirty;
}).extend({ rateLimit: 500 });

 this.isDirty.subscribe(function(changes) {
    console.log("context changed " + new Date().getTime());
});
```

So my code could be modifying `types`, `instances`, `selection` or `filters` at any point and I don't really want to have to care about this too much. Realistically there will be several modifications in rapid succession (e.g. a new item is added into `types` and `selection` is modified at the same time).

The problem I've got is that even with the `rateLimit` that I've tried adding, I seem to be getting multiple fires, and I don't understand why. Here's the console output when I make a change:

> context.js:59 isDirty changed 1455203776330
>   context.js:52 types changed 1455203776331
>   context.js:53 instances changed 1455203776333
>   context.js:54 selection changed 1455203776333
>   context.js:55 filters changed 1455203776333
>   context.js:52 types changed 1455203776334
>   context.js:53 instances changed 1455203776334
>   context.js:54 selection changed 1455203776335
>   context.js:52 types changed 1455203776409
>   context.js:53 instances changed 1455203776413
>   context.js:54 selection changed 1455203776413
>   context.js:59 isDirty changed 1455203776832
>   context.js:68 context changed 1455203776832
>   context.js:59 isDirty changed 1455203776912
>   context.js:68 context changed 1455203776913

So I can't figure out why after making all my changes (e.g. `selection` changes at `1455203776413` is the last change) why `isDirty` then fires twice afterwards...

I'll add that I'm trying to put together a snippet to reproduce this error, although that doesn't seem to be working at present. I'm just trying to figure out what other parts of my code could be introducing side affects to this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lesson here - ensure that you've only got a single item you're tracking. It just so happens that there was a **copy** of the `ViewModel` that was being passed around and this was also triggering to the console.